# Function in python to accept a local folder

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I need to post a folder to the server from my local when method == POST.

Is there any request module in python using which we can upload a folder to server?

I have used the below to accept the file.
request.files.getlist('files'). 
When I use this method along with webkitdirectory in the input tag of my html file it returns the file along with the foldername. But I'm looking to get only folder name, as I have a written seperate function to retrieve the data from folder.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files.getlist('files')
        print(files)

HTML- Tag:
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>
    <p>Parse CV</p>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files" webkitdirectory='' multiple='' >
    <input type="submit" value="Upload CV" name="submit">
</h3>
    </form>
```

The above code will allow me to upload a directory but it returns something like : '/uploads/123.pdf','/uploads/234.docx','/uploads/345.txt'.

Instead I want something like :'/uploads'
Where uploads is my folder in local.

So is there any module in python which accepts a folder and return the folder name?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the name of the folder (uploads in this case) you can get it from the list of files in your `files` variable like this:

```
from os.path import dirname
files = request.files.getlist('files')
folder = dirname(files[0].filename)
```

Comment: No it dint help me. Its throwing error as:  zipfile.BadZipFile : File is not a zip file

Comment: That seems a different problem, maybe you should edit the question to reflect that part of the code that you are not showing and seems to be involved (trying to open the zip file).

Comment: Thanks Jacalvo. I have written the code in another question ''Upload folder and return the output in json format'' can you please help me in understanding where I'm missing?